# Random integers coming from the "write" system call are not recognized from the "read" system call in C

Tags: c, random, integer, system-calls

I am trying to write a fixed number of random integers into a file, using the system call "write", and then check if they are written properly. In order to do this, I call the "read" function, then I read all the file content, integer by integer and I print them into another file.

The problem is that although the write function writes properly the random integers (500 in size), the read function is able to extract e.g 200 of them and then it returns garbage for the rest 300. Sometimes, it returns only 10 of them. Every time I run the code, it has a different behavior.

I have checked that the "write" function writes all the numbers correctly by printing them to another file (e.g file1). But, printing the numbers that the "read" function returns (e.g. file2) showed me that they are not all the same.

I realized that if I use a single number (e.g. 5) instead of a random integer, it all works fine. I googled a lot, I checked if I open/close the files properly and I could not solve the problem.

Here is my code in C. I removed some error checks in order to show you a small script.
Can you please help me?

```
int main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );

    // write
    int fd = open("file_test_1", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    int val;
    if (fd != -1) {
        for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
            val = (int) rand()%500;
           // val = 5;
            write(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
        }
    }
    close(fd);

    FILE * file_check;
    file_check=fopen("file_test_1_check","w");

   // test read
    fd = open("file_test_1", O_RDONLY);
    int new_val;
    int x;
    if (fd != -1) {
        while(  ( x = read(fd, &new_val, sizeof(new_val)) )>0 ){
            fprintf(file_check,"%d\t\t%d\n",new_val, x);
        }

    }
    close(fd);
    fclose(file_check);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: example of what you get as data and garbage?

Comment: Just tried it out. Works fine. Need more info.

Comment: I just tried it, using S_IWUSR as the the third argument of the first open call, to set read rights to the file owner. It's still not working.

Comment: Well, I print to the file_test_1_check the random number and the bytes from read function.
So, I executed the code the 1st time and I got something like: 492 4, 177 4 ... for 200 lines. But, in the second execution, I got 300 lines such that and then 90368 4, 127488 4, ... for 100 other lines.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. You might try posting minimal complete compilable code that reproduces your symptom.

Comment: Thank you Lee. I am not very sure about what you mean. I am not also sure about where the problem is. In random generation, in file opening arguments, in the read/write calls? The only thing I'm sure is that with a constant number (not random) in  the val variable it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `O_CREAT` to open a file, you need to set file permissions for subsequent users. You do that by specifiying the **pmode**, ie OR ing the combination of the flags `S_IREAD` `S_IWRITE` (go ahead and use both). Also since you're writing a binary, it wouldn't hurt informing the system with `O_BINARY`. So the correct `open` would be :

```
int fd = open("file_test_1", O_BINARY | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | S_IREAD);
```

Now, when you reopen that file, you **really** need to open it in binary form, so the correct subsequent open would be :

```
fd = open("file_test_1", O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `open` call is wrong. Per the man page, when you pass `O_CREAT` in the `oflag` argument to `open`, a third `mode` argument is required. This will be the access mode for the file. On my system, `open` is seeing 0 for the omitted third argument (left-over value in a register or on the stack), so the next `open` (to read the file) fails.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I read this example [http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open]. So, I should probably write : (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR) in the arguments, to be able to read again the file?

Comment: I tried the above combination of arguments and also this: O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR and I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It works for me. Did you remove the old file first? If the old file (with the 000 mode) still exists, its permissions won't be changed (since the `open` call isn't creating it).

Comment: I tried to have it removed and not removed. Still the same unpredictable results from the read function.